# asp.net authentication problems basic/windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, basic-authentication

I am looking at an intranet site (not developed by me) and it has basic authentication enabled.
It needs to be changed to Windows authentication and I have done just that in IIS.

Basically I have installed the Visual Studio 2010 Remote debugger to check why it works fine using basic auth but when changed to Windows it doesn't.

It hangs on the first line on the try, on error 401 unauthorized:

```
        oReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        oReq.Method = "POST";

        // Set the script timeout to a desired value. Timeout value is specified in milliseconds.
        oReq.Timeout = 60000;

        WindowsIdentity wId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        WindowsIdentity wIdb4 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        string name = wIdb4.Name;
        WindowsImpersonationContext wIdCon = wId.Impersonate();

        // Set credentials to use for this request. 
        oReq.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        Stream oDataStream = oReq.GetRequestStream();

        // Use EncodeParam to enocde the parameters passed in the URL
        String sParam = "...";

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] Buffer = encoding.GetBytes(sParam);
        oDataStream.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        oDataStream.Close();
try
   {
      HttpWebResponse oResp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
      ....
   }
```

Makes no sense, how come it gets pased it with basic auth and not with Windows?
Also when I run the site on the local machine asp.net server, it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried setting `oReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true`?

Comment: There's really not enough information on this one. What account does the site run as? Who is connecting to what, how are all sites configured and which server or site throws the error?

Comment: Dylan: I am using `oReq.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;` would that do it for Window auth? It works fine for Basic.

Comment: Dylan: Have tried defaultcreds but no change. @CodeCaster the site is on a local server, same domain as anyone accessing it.

Comment: Have NTFS permissions been applied to the relevant files in the site?